# IoT sending packets from devices to webserver

Tags: java, azure, server, iot, azure-iot-hub

I'm working on a project with a lot of IoT devices. Those devices will me planted and will send data to me. Now my question is: How can I receive this data and process this with my webserver (java) so I can put this information, which will be send by those devices, on my website.
I read something about azure IoT Hub and something about the things network but I can't connect the dots right now.

Do you have any ideas how to do this? I'm already using a network so I can connect to something like The Things network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IoT Hubs is the cloud service for building scalable IoT solutions - you can use it as a some-kind-of-very-scalable queue for messages that are coming from your devices or your gateway. Someone should be on the other end of the queue and process the messages. It can be Stream Analytics service (which is the service that implements the very difficult task - polling the queue and processing the messages and passing them further).

I would highly recommend you to go through the test solution Microsoft developed - it is called connect-the-dots :-) You may find it [here](https://github.com/Psychlist1972/connectthedots/tree/IoT-Field-Labs/Devices/DirectlyConnectedDevices), and it goes through all of the components you may want for implementing the solution - from different devices and queues to the analytics and visualization.

The reference architecture from Microsoft can be found in [Azure IoT Suite site](http://azureiotsuite.com) - it has the remote monitoring solution. You just need to register the Azure account, and then click to deploy. The end-to-end remote monitoring solution will be deployed, and you will be able to review the architecture and understand the flows.

For sending your messages through the gateway, you can use one of two (or both somehow) ways:

1) To pass the messages through that gateway - just send it to your gateway, then your gateway can check if everything is OK with the message and send it to the IoT Hub (queue) for processing. You can not do that in the IoT Hub itself, so you can guarantee that incoming messages will have the appropriate format, etc.

2) To send the message to the gateway, then gateway will accumulate some amount of messages into one "big" message and send it to the queue to avoid the situation when you send a lot of identical messages. It should be done with caution as, for the obvious reason, the information will be "average", but not exact the same. But you can accumulate the messages into something like the archive, then put it to the Azure Storage and send the link to that file to the IoT Hub. Then the processing worker will take the message, download the file and start the processing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know how you can send the packets which you receive from the nodes through http to my webserver?

Comment: See updated answer - too long for the comment :-)

Comment: Thank you! It really helped!

Comment: Great! Mark the question as answered, if so, please, for a future reference.